# Обязательно ли в структуре json должны быть квадратные скобки?

Tags: javascript, php, json

Обязательно ли в структуре json, по стандарту должны быть квадратные скобки, при перечислении однотипных полей ?

например:

```
{
   "persons" : {[
       {
       "name": 'vasya',
       "age": 21,
       },
       {
       "name": "123",
       "age": 123
       }
    ]}
}
```

обязательно ли нужно указывать ли нужно указывать квадратные скобки, или в чем отличие??

Comment: В чем отличие от __чего__?

Comment: идем на https://jsoneditoronline.org/  вставляем ваш `JSON`, видим что он не валидный. `[]` означают массив, `{}` объект. У вас в объекте нет полей, но зато есть массив. Либо вы пропустили ключи, либо не правильно написали `JSON`

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru/ — Вам стоит ознакомиться с 4 и 5 пунктами, про объекты и массивы) JSON - всего лишь структура данных, состоящая из объектов или массивов, или и того и другого. Всё зависит от задачи.

Comment: То что вы написали это не JSON. Про отличия рекомендую выяснить разницу между массивами и объектами

Comment: `{[]}` - это не валидная запись, `{"key": []}` либо так, либо так `[]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы открываете `json` файл фигурной скобкой, и закрываете его тоже. Получается так:

```
{

    ...something

}
```

`json` - это ассоциативный массив (ключ: значение), а для ассоциативного массива в JavaScript языке используются фигурные скобки `{}`. **JSON** - JavaScript Object Natation., поэтому в `jsqon` используется синтаксис `JavaScript`.

Квадратные скобки в языке `JavaScript` обозначают обычный массив типа `[1,2,3,4]`, когда фигурные подразумевают объект:

```
{

    "name": "Jason",
    "age": 18

}
```

Почему же вам приходится иногда писать квадратные скобки в `json`? Все просто. Когда какой-либо "ключ" содержит значения массив(обычный), т.е. просто перечисление.

**Примеры**

```
{

  "name": "Jason",
  "age": 18,

  "education": ["school", "college"],

  "home": {
    "land": "USA",
    "state": "Florida"
  },

  "parents": [

    {"role": "father", "name": "Alex"},
    {"role": "mother", "name": "Julia"}

  ]

}
```

---

`{}` - задаем объект, `key: value`

`[]` - просто перечисляем, `[{},{},{}]` или `[1,2,3,{}]`

Comment: Спасибо большое.
А если такая запись: 
"parents": {

    {"role": "father", "name": "Alex"},
    {"role": "mother", "name": "Julia"}

  }

Comment: Т.е. без квадратных скобок, это уже невалидный json ?

Comment: Смотрите, у вас ключ `parents`, и вы хотите присвоить ему массив объектов. Значит вы должны сделать так `"parents": [{},{},{}]`, потому что `[]` - означает перечисление, объяснил что бы вы поняли)

Comment: Почувствуйте разницу, между перечислением `[]` и между объектом `{}`.

Comment: Если помог, то можете поставить галочку)

Answer (score 0):

На первых порах изучения текстовых форматов удобно использовать визуализаторы, которые помогут вам помочь понять структуру вашего или чужого объекта.

Для json например [jsonviewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

попробуйте, так на много проще.

```
  "json_1": {
    "persons": [
      {
        "name": "vasya",
        "age": 21
      },
      {
        "name": "123",
        "age": 123
      }
    ]
  },
  "json_2": {
    "persons": {
      "vasya": {
        "age": 21
      },
      "123": {
        "age": 123
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]